# How to control Adaptive Sampling in .NET Core application

Tags: azure, .net-core, azure-application-insights

I'm trying to limit the amount of data sent to Application Insights in a .NET Core program.  I'm attempting to follow the documention [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/sampling) which says I should use the `UseAdaptiveSampling` method.  It has the rather cryptic instruction:

> > Use extension methods of TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder as shown below to customize sampling behavior.

However, it doesn't tell me *where* exactly this extension method lives.  My code is as follows:

```
public AppInsightsStats(string appInsightsKey)
{
    TelemetryConfiguration configuration = TelemetryConfiguration.CreateDefault();
    configuration.InstrumentationKey = appInsightsKey;
    telemetry = new TelemetryClient(configuration);
    // Enable sampling since amount of logging is massive
    var builder = configuration.DefaultTelemetrySink.TelemetryProcessorChainBuilder;
    builder.UseAdaptiveSampling(maxTelemetryItemsPerSecond:5); // <-- Compiler error here
}
```

However, the code doesn't compile since `UseAdaptiveSampling` isn't found.  I have the following `using` statements:

```
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.DataContracts;
using Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.Extensibility;
```

The source code I can dig up that uses `UseAdaptiveSampling` all seems to be .NET Framework 4.5 code, so I'm wondering if this just isn't included with the .NET Core version.  These instructions are for ASP.NET Core, but I'm wondering if they mean running that on the .NET Framework on Windows.

Comment: it is a .net core web project or console project?

Comment: Console project..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For console project, you should use this package [Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.WorkerService](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-monitor/app/worker-service). It's used for non-http application like console project.

I used your code with this package, everything is ok. Please give it a try, and let me know if you still have the issue.

Comment: That worked!  Yea, I was missing the NuGet package which was the problem.  I'm guessing that NuGet package is pulled in automatically with all the ASP.NET Core stuff, which I'm not using..  Wish they had a documentation example for standard .NET Core console apps.